# What is this pulse experiment showing?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-state, ibm-q-experience

The following results in the figure were achieved using Qiskit pulse by doing the following pulse sequence;

{ $\frac{\pi}{2}$, delay $\tau$, $\pi$, delay $\tau$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$}

[image]

The figure is the average of 1024 shots.

This experiment looks very similar to applying the following sequence which is done to measure the T1 time of a qubit which is the it takes a qubit to decay to its ground state from its excited state;

{ $\pi$, delay $\tau$, $\pi$, delay $\tau$, $\pi$ }

I am trying to understand what the first experiment is used for and what the the results from the figure even show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a T2 experiment with an echo (i.e., a Hahn echo experiment)

Comment: Are you talking about the Hahn echo experiment? If you are then I thought it was that too but in the Qiskit textbook, the graph grows exponentially rather than decaying exponentially like in the figure in my question.

https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-quantum-hardware/calibrating-qubits-pulse.html#hahn

Comment: I guess that it depends on whether the y axis is the probability to measure 0 or 1